# ColorMatrix equivalent on the WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Specifically, I'm trying to port some C# code to windows phone platform. I've come across a number of articles recommending using custom pixel shaders with XNA, but that isn't supported on the WP7 platform. I can always write my own matrix transformation library, but I'd prefer to use built in libraries.

My question is, is there a recommended way for doing color transformations using matrices on an image on a wp7 device?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? Can you give a screenshot? There are options but it will depend on your performance requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you want, I think you'll want to take at the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library. It's very efficient and has a lot of effects out of the box. If you want more custom drawing routines, you could use this library to read and write pixel data whilst using [XNA's Matrix class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.aspx) to perform the data calculations.